# How to stop logging in a node in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3. Currently, all my nodes have logging enabled by default. How do I prevent a particular node from logging anything but Error logs? The other nodes should do logging as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on every node inside the config folder there is one file `log4j2.properties`. Usually on ubuntu based machines this file reside in `/etc/elasticsearch/` for debian and RPM

Each node has its own configuration so changing the configuration for one node will not effect other nodes.

There you can set `logger.action.level = error` for the node you want to stop logging.

```
# log action execution errors for easier debugging
logger.action.name = org.elasticsearch.action
logger.action.level = error
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this require restarting the ES node?